# What fonts or typefaces were commonly used in old (pre-1950) mathematics literature?

Tags: math-history

I recall reading some books in my university library which were published in the 1920s and 1930s, and am wondering about their fonts. They looked very nice, and I would like to find some. It seems Monotype Modern was one such font, but it somehow costs hundreds of dollars despite the fact that its creator has been dead for a century.

Are there open source versions of such classic mathematical fonts?

Comment: The [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) might be a better place for this question. *Possibly*, people on the [TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com) might have insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Hint:**  Some related information is given in *[Mathematical Typography](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183544082)* by D.E. Knuth from 1979. He discusses  aspects of the development of typography used in *AMS Transactions* from 1900 up to the late 1970s  in order to introduce $\TeX$ and $\mathrm{METAFONT}$.